# How to show select_advanced content instead of ID?

Tags: metabox

When I am using this code, it only shows the ID instead of its content. I want to show the content instead, how can fix this?

```
array(
    'name' => __( 'Select Home Team ', 'themepixels' ),
    'id' => "{$prefix}select_home_team",
    'type' => 'post',
    'post_type' =>  'football_team' ,
    'options' => array(
    'type' => 'select_advanced',
    'args' => array()
    ),
    'multiple' => false,
),
```

.....

```
   <div class="home-team">
       <?php $home_team_name = rwmb_meta( 'pb_select_home_team', 'type=select_advanced', get_the_ID() ); ?>
      <?php  echo esc_html( $home_team_name  ); ?>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
 echo get_the_title($home_team_name)
```